# Polymer How to use condition to display different elements depending on boolean returned by function?

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

I have been trying to solve this problem, but without success.

My code is:

```
[...]
    <script src="lib/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="lib/polymer/polymer.html">
    <link rel="import" href="components/app-layout.html">
    <link rel="import" href="components/disconnected-layout.html">
</head>
<body unresolved>
    <template>
        <script>
        Polymer({
            connected: function() {
                var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xmlHttp.open( "GET", "127.0.0.1:5021", false );
                xmlHttp.send( null );
                var connection = JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText);
                if (connection.success == undefined)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                return !!connnection.success;
            }
        });
        </script>
[...]
```

This part above checks for connection to server.

In the next part there should be choosen right display:

```
[...]
        <template is="dom-if" if="{{connected()}}">
            <app-layout></app-layout>
        </template>
        <template is="dom-if" if="{{!connected()}}">
            <disconnected-layout></disconnected-layout>
        </template>
[...]
```

But instead of connected/disconnected layout browser is showing blank page.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Polymer bindings are for binding to properties or "computed properties", which are properties that are dynamically generated from a function when certain other properties are changed.

You could try a normal property like this:

```
Polymer({
  properties: {
    connected: {
      type: Boolean,
      value: function() {
        // code which returns true/false depending on whether you're connected
      }
    }
  }
});
```

When Polymer creates your element it'll run that function to determine the initial value of the `connected` property, which can then be bound to like in your example. It's important to note that this is calculated once and so if your client later goes offline `connected` will not be updated.

Computed Properties are similar, except they allow you to define other properties on the element which your property depends on:

```
Polymer({
  properties: {
    otherProperty: String,
    connected: {
      type: Boolean,
      computed: '_isConnected(otherProperty)'
    }
  },

  _isConnected: function(otherProperty) {
    return otherProperty !== null;
  }
})
```

This will cause your property to update any time the other property changes.

Depending on your application, it's likely that you'll want to subscribe to the [online and offline events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Online_and_offline_events) of your browser to dynamically update this, setting `connected` to `true` or `false` in your event handler for that.

It looks like you have specific logic for detecting connectivity: looking for a response from a server running on your machine. You may end up needing to create an interval (`setInterval`) to check that regularly and update the property accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for response, but it still does not work. I also tried to hardcode value to true, but without effect.